# Lyx - Problem with Acknowledgements in the Environment Box

Tags: lyx

I use the document class "book(more font sizes)", with language setup as "French".
When I want to select the french equivalent of Acknowledgements in the Environment box, it is written "Remerciements(inconnu)" (inconnu means unknown) and when I select it to add the acknowledgments in my text, nothing happens.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the document class (is it `extbook`?) used doesn't define any specific environment or command for acknowledgments, and if no LyX module defines it either, then there is nothing to add. That is probably the reason it says 'unknown' as well.

I don't know exactly how you want to display these acknowledgements, but you could for example just add an unnumbered chapter, and call it *Acknowledgements*.